# jQuery autocomplete disable filtering, show everything

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a jQ autocomplete field linked to an AJAX call and the server is doing all of the filtering for me (from a database of hundreds of thousands of items). All I really need the autocomplete widget for is the nice inputbox/dropdown combo functionality.

Basically, and perhaps unintuitively, I'm asking whether there is a way to use jQuery autocomplete having disabled the autocomplete, because the AJAX call always returns all of the required selection items.

Comment: code code, need some code. show some code

Comment: @AtanuCSE I solved the problem, but out of interest, what code would you have wanted to see? I could have pasted the autocomplete example from the jQuery documentation, but it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me being stupid. This is already the default setting for the widget, as specified in the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):

> Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results.